# Select the first value with Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I would like to select the first value of the following code:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="PARENT-CHILD">Parent-Child (1:Many)</option>
    <option value="PRIMARY-SECONDARY">Primary-Secondary (1:Many)</option
    <option value="ASSOCIATED-TO">Associated To (Many:Many)</option>
</select>
```

Code Tried :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"popover162353\"]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/select")).click();

new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"popover162353\"]/div[2]/div/form/div/div[1]/div[1]/select"))).selectByVisibleText("Parent-Child (1:Many)");
```

Html:

```
<div class="popover-content">
<div>
    <div class="editableform-loading" style="display: none;"></div>
    <form class="form-inline editableform" style="">
        <div class="control-group form-group">
            <div>
                <div class="editable-input">
                    <select class="form-control input-sm">
                        <option value="PARENT-CHILD">Parent-Child (1:Many)</option>
                        <option value="PRIMARY-SECONDARY">Primary-Secondary (1:Many)</option>
                        <option –value="ASSOCIATED-TO">Associated To (Many:Many)</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="editable-buttons">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-cancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="editable-error-block help-block" style="display: none;"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: please show some html code for the locator you want to access.

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: <select class="form-control input-sm"><option value="PARENT-CHILD">Parent-Child (1:Many)</option><option value="PRIMARY-SECONDARY">Primary-Secondary (1:Many)</option><option value="ASSOCIATED-TO">Associated To (Many:Many)</option></select>

Comment: There is a mismatch between the _HTML_ you have provided and the _absolute xpath_ in your code trial. Can you cross check once again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop down is made using select and option tag. You can use select class from selenium.

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select.form-control.input-sm")))  

dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Primary-Secondary (1:Many)");
```

or using value attribute.

```
dropdown.selectByValue("PRIMARY-SECONDARY");
```

**EDIT** :

You may try with this code :

```
Select dropdown = new Select(new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("select.form-control.input-sm")))); 
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("Primary-Secondary (1:Many)");
```

Comment: I tried your solution but the same value is not selected

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=67.0.3396.99)

Comment: You can try with the updated code from edit section.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.cssSelector: select.form-control.input-sm (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'

Comment: print this `System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("select.form-control.input-sm")).size());` , and let me know the output.

Comment: it printed me 24

Comment: that means there are 24 classes with `form-control.input-sm` , you will have to find the unique one for drop down. Either you can share the more outer HTML or if the URL is public , then you can share with us ?

Comment: <div class="popover-content"> <div><div class="editableform-loading" style="display: none;"></div><form class="form-inline editableform" style=""><div class="control-group form-group"><div><div class="editable-input"><select class="form-control input-sm"><option value="PARENT-CHILD">Parent-Child (1:Many)</option><option value="PRIMARY-SECONDARY">Primary-Secondary (1:Many)</option><option

Comment: value="ASSOCIATED-TO">Associated To (Many:Many)</option></select></div><div class="editable-buttons"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm editable-submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm editable-cancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button></div></div><div class="editable-error-block help-block" style="display: none;"></div></div></form></div></div>

Comment: I split into two

Comment: Check if you get only one element with `driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.popover-content form.editableform  select.form-control.input-sm")).size();` and use @cruisepandey solution. You can remove not needed parts of selector.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
WebElement temp = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control input-sm']")));
Select findValue= new Select(temp);
findValue.selectByValue("PARENT-CHILD");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways already mention , you can use different methods like

```
    WebElement dropdownEle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@class='form-control input-sm']"));
    Select Dropdown = new Select(dropdownEle);
    Dropdown.selectByIndex(1);
    //Dropdown.selectByValue("Parent-Child (1:Many)");
    //Dropdown.selectByValue("Primary-Secondary (1:Many)");
```

You can use `selectByIndex(index)` or `selectByValue(value)` or `selectByVisibleText(text)`, but the bet way to use it using `selectByValue(value)`